# EXcel COUNT values based on multiple conditions in different ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, count, multiple-conditions

I have an Excel spreadsheet, contain all possible combinations between certain products, e.g. `a-a, a-b, a-c, b-a, b-b, b-c, c-a, c-b and c-c`. Based on those combinations, a value is calculated and compared with a historical value. The two values are subtracted, resulting in -1, 0 or 1.

Now, in another spreadsheet, I have all the products listed (so that would be a, b and c here) and for each product, I would like to know how many -1's, 0's and 1's the product had as a result when it was the second product in the combination, e.g. I want to know how many ...-b's resulted in 0.

My first thought was to use a simple `COUNTIF`, going over the range with the subtraction: `COUNTIF(RANGE:0)`. Of course, this gives all the 0's in the range, without taking into account the product. Then, I tried `SUM(IF(AND("range of the second product"="b";"range of the subtraction result"=0);1))`, but this produces `#N/A`. I am unsure what to try out next.

In some other related topics, the suggestion was made to make use of arrays, based on http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx

Consequently, I tried the formula `{=COUNT(("2ndproductrange"="b") * ("resultrange"<0))}`, but this returned the total number of rows. A variant with `{=COUNTIF(("2ndproductrange"="b")*("resultrange");<0)}` isn't a valid formula.

Comment: Going back to your `SUM(IF...` idea, try `=SUM(IF(productrange = product b, IF(subtractionrange = 0, product column, 0), 0))` and hit CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER when editing the cell.

Comment: maybe I am missing something but it sounds like you just want a simple `COUNTIFS` with multiple criteria and ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like to me that you are trying to perform a `COUNT` operation that matches 2 distinct criteria.  As you noted the `COUNTIF` formula takes in a single criteria, well there is a `COUNTIFS` formula that takes in multiple.  Here is what I "think" it would look like with your example ranges:

```
=COUNTIFS(2ndproductrange;"b";resultrange;"<0")
```

A concrete example would be as follows:

```
       A               B       C       D        E   F   G
---------------------------------------------------------
Historical Value    Product        Countifs     a   b   c
       1               c              <0        1   2   0
      -1               a               0        0   1   1
      -1               b              >0        1   2   1
       1               b                    
       1               b                    
       0               c                    
      -1               b                    
       0               b                    
       1               a
```

In the above example the formulas would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B;"a";$A:$A;"<0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B;"b";$A:$A;"<0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B;"c";$A:$A;"<0")
=COUNTIFS($B:$B;"a";$A:$A;"0")  =COUNTIFS($B:$B;"b";$A:$A;"0")  =COUNTIFS($B:$B;"c";$A:$A;"0")
=COUNTIFS($B:$B;"a";$A:$A;">0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B;"b";$A:$A;">0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B;"c";$A:$A;">0")
```

For those that are using a comma `,` as their list separator locale the same formulas would be:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"a",$A:$A,"<0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B,"b",$A:$A,"<0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B,"c",$A:$A,"<0")
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"a",$A:$A,"0")  =COUNTIFS($B:$B,"b",$A:$A,"0")  =COUNTIFS($B:$B,"c",$A:$A,"0")
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"a",$A:$A,">0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B,"b",$A:$A,">0") =COUNTIFS($B:$B,"c",$A:$A,">0")
```